# How to squash two last commits into one and take the Change I form the last but one commit?

Tags: git, commit

If I execute `git log`, I see on the top two commits done by me. Each commit comes with its change ID.

Now I would like to squash this commit into one. It means that I want these two commits to come as one commit with one commit message.

Moreover, I want that the combined commit gets the Change ID from the last but one commit.

Comment: `git rebase -i` and use `pick` and `fixup` respectively when prompted for your two commits

Comment: What is the "Change ID"? Something in your commit message? So just use `squash` and edit the message to keep the parts you want from the two original commits' messages.

Comment: This question is a duplicate.  Note that when you squash two commits, you will have the chance to edit the final commit message at which point you can make any changes you want w/r/t the change id embedded in the message.

Comment: Also, assuming by 'Change ID' you mean the `SHA` of the commit, you won't be able to have the new combined commit retain the `SHA` of either of the original ones; by necessity it will change because it's a new commit.